# SIGPIPE crash when request is more than 4MB

Tags: mysql, xcode

I use Xcode 3.2.1 (I am on snow leopard for some reasons) with mysql :

- Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL) +
- mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-osx10.6-x86_64

I am passing a request to mysql_query() as follows.

```
// mysql request
request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE consult SET summary='%@', pheno='%@' WHERE idConsult=%@", sum, phe, idc];

if (mysql_query(mysqlCnx,[request UTF8String])) {
   db_finish_with_error(mysqlCnx);
}
```

When the request size is more than 4MB, I get a SIGPIPE with the following stack trace :

```
#0  0x7fff896d791e in sendto
#1  0x100065a92 in vio_write
#2  0x10004d2a2 in net_write_packet
#3  0x10004d3ac in net_write_buff
#4  0x10004d6e2 in net_write_command
#5  0x100048e3c in cli_advanced_command
#6  0x100046bdd in mysql_real_query
#7  0x1000093f9 in -[ConsultList mysqlUpdateResumePhenoFields:] at ConsultList.m:163
4#8 0x10000a565 in -[ConsultList okConsult:] at ConsultList.m:367
```

Any known issue ?

Comment: It got me with XCODE 6 and Swift - but of course this error does not depend on that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here was the solution  :

```
/etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=120M 

as root :
chown 644 /etc/my.cnf

mysql> set global max_allowed_packet = 125829120;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 125829120 |  << 120MB !
+--------------------+-----------+
```